# what are advantages of queue over multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, architecture, queue, jms

Message queues might also be used internally in a program, in which case it's often just a facility to exchange/queue data from a producer thread to a consumer thread to do async processing.

now for async processing I can simply create threads ... if I am using queue internally isn't this a overhead for doing async processing ???

Please answer in yes or no with valid explaination.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a thread takes much longer than a producer thread pushing a buffer, task or object pointer onto a queue and subsequent dequeueing by a consumer thread, so the inevitable overhead is much less than continually creating threads.

If you continually create threads, you have to continually terminate and destroy them.  This is more overhead and, anyway, often goes wrong, resulting in thread runaway, shutdown failures and obscure memory leaks.

Thread pools, and app-lifetime threads, are safer, cleaner, easier to debug and less prone to disastrous failures/errors and, worse, intermittent 'deviations from specification':)

Answer (score 0):

> what are advantages of queue over multiple threads

I think the advantages are related to non-functional requirements such as Reliability:

- if an error happens when a message is processed, it can remain in the queue until the process executes ok.
- one step further is to persist the message in a database, which allows you to process the message later if the system suddenly fails.

> if I am using queue internally isn't this a overhead for doing async processing

it depends whether the non-functional requirements listed above are important for your application, otherwise create a new thread could be enough.